# clear sessions created in jmeter for each iternation of the loop controller

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies, jmeter-plugins

i have a jmeter tree as below.

**Tree**

```
ThreadGroup(20users,1 loop count)
cookie manager
launch
login
Loop controller(30times)
    https request1
          sessionID-1
    https request2
          sessionID-2   
    https request2
```

Cookie manager clears cookie values before each iteration of the users (thread loop count value)(-- correct me if i'm wrong) not the cookie values during the each iteration of the loop controller element in jmeter.

Hence my requirement is, i would like to clear all the sessions created during the each iteration of the loop controller component before going to next iteration.

Update :I would like to clear only those sessions created inside the loop controller.not the one which created above the loop contoller(Launch&login)which should be used in https request1 .

And session created at https request1 is used at https request 4 which is there in the same loop controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to clear the session values stored locally during the run time.But unless you kill the connections u can not actually break the connections made to DB (for example).If you clear the sessions using above answer, those session will be open until the time out set, however you wont be able access those since you have cleared from your local storage.

So when you log out from the application you must find session close request. you can use that request and have in your jmeter script at the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the `https request1`
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.getCookieManager().clear()
   ```
3. That's it, you will get clear session on each Loop Controller's iteration.

You might also be interested in [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy) article to learn what else can be done with the cookies using Groovy scripting

Comment: hi Dmitri T, thanks for your reply. Instead having as a child of request, is there any way at the end of the each loop controller i can clear all the sessions created.This would help me a lot as i may use the session created in https request 1 in https request 4.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T ,please can u check,i have updated my question